# How to create a spiral block in blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Hi I am trying to create the following structure in blender. I tried to create a plane and then loop cut it into several pieces. Then used the simple deform on it to bend it around a circle and extruce in z but it is not giving the desired output. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I also tried to create a circle and poke faces in edit mode. Then extruded in z direction but not working.

[image]

Edit: I am able to get it and I used the freestyle option to render the edges but it is showing some extra edges like below, how to get rid of the extra edges?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a single edge from the center to the side.

[image: single edge]

Add a screw modifier with a positive *screw* value.

[image: screw modifier]

Fill <kbd>F</kbd> the created n-gon (1) and add a triangle (2), connecting the first point and the last segment.

[image: fill faces]

Select the border edge loop <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and extrude it downwards <kbd>E</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>. Scale the extruded edgeloop to 0 along the Z-axis. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>
I added an edge split modifier to sharp the sharp edges.

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I am looking for.I am able to create it now. How to chow the edges when rendering the image? Also how to apply different colors to different edges?Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Add a circle in Edit mode Press F

select 2 faces and delete the rest

Add Empty -> Add Array Modifier

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1S40.jpg